# Sorting a vector by time

Tags: r

I have a factor variable which is comprised of times. When I attempt to turn it into a factor, R orders them in order from lowest to highest. Unforunately, this means that I end up with something like the following:

```
1:48:55  1:53:11  1:58:18  10:04:01 10:12:45 10:14:16 
10:20:24 10:21:59 10:23:11 10:23:40 10:30:40 10:34:13 
10:39:47 10:54:33 10:58:43 3:21:59  3:27:38  3:37:58  
3:49:00 4:20:42  4:30:52  4:37:39  4:40:08  4:40:55  
4:42:25  5:03:25  5:10:30  5:10:49  5:12:39  5:14:20
```

So instead of printing the times in order, times with 10:00 come before 7:00.

Is there a quick way to order the times by the actual time?

```
    time = c("1:48:55", "1:53:11", "1:58:18", "10:04:01", "10:12:45", "10:14:16", "10:20:24", "10:21:59", "10:23:11", "10:23:40", "10:30:40", "10:34:13", "10:39:47", "10:54:33", "10:58:43", "3:21:59", "3:27:38", "3:37:58", "3:49:00", "4:20:42", "4:30:52", "4:37:39",  "4:40:08", "4:40:55", "4:42:25", "5:03:25", "5:10:30", "5:10:49", "5:12:39", "5:14:20")

time = factor(time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(chron)
sort(times(time))
```

or this if you want the sorted vector to remain a factor:

```
time[order(times(time))]
```

Answer (score 2):

The items are in the order they are in, so it you use `factor` they will stay in that order but you could set the levels in a way that would let regressions report them "properly". The `mixedsort` function in gtools will sort such character vectors as expected:

```
require(gtools)
mixedsort(time)
 [1] "1:48:55"  "1:53:11"  "1:58:18"  "3:21:59"  "3:27:38"  "3:37:58"  "3:49:00"  "4:20:42"  "4:30:52" 
[10] "4:37:39"  "4:40:08"  "4:40:55"  "4:42:25"  "5:03:25"  "5:10:30"  "5:10:49"  "5:12:39"  "5:14:20" 
[19] "10:04:01" "10:12:45" "10:14:16" "10:20:24" "10:21:59" "10:23:11" "10:23:40" "10:30:40" "10:34:13"
[28] "10:39:47" "10:54:33" "10:58:43"

> time=factor(time, levels= mixedsort(time))
> levels(time)
 [1] "1:48:55"  "1:53:11"  "1:58:18"  "3:21:59"  "3:27:38"  "3:37:58"  "3:49:00"  "4:20:42"  "4:30:52" 
[10] "4:37:39"  "4:40:08"  "4:40:55"  "4:42:25"  "5:03:25"  "5:10:30"  "5:10:49"  "5:12:39"  "5:14:20" 
[19] "10:04:01" "10:12:45" "10:14:16" "10:20:24" "10:21:59" "10:23:11" "10:23:40" "10:30:40" "10:34:13"
[28] "10:39:47" "10:54:33" "10:58:43"
> time
 [1] 1:48:55  1:53:11  1:58:18  10:04:01 10:12:45 10:14:16 10:20:24 10:21:59 10:23:11 10:23:40 10:30:40
[12] 10:34:13 10:39:47 10:54:33 10:58:43 3:21:59  3:27:38  3:37:58  3:49:00  4:20:42  4:30:52  4:37:39 
[23] 4:40:08  4:40:55  4:42:25  5:03:25  5:10:30  5:10:49  5:12:39  5:14:20 
30 Levels: 1:48:55 1:53:11 1:58:18 3:21:59 3:27:38 3:37:58 3:49:00 4:20:42 4:30:52 4:37:39 ... 10:58:43
```

If you want them to get sorted as time values you will need to choose a time class to work with. The chron package is one possible choice:

```
time = c("1:48:55", "1:53:11", "1:58:18", "10:04:01", "10:12:45", "10:14:16", "10:20:24", "10:21:59", "10:23:11", "10:23:40", "10:30:40", "10:34:13", "10:39:47", "10:54:33", "10:58:43", "3:21:59", "3:27:38", "3:37:58", "3:49:00", "4:20:42", "4:30:52", "4:37:39",  "4:40:08", "4:40:55", "4:42:25", "5:03:25", "5:10:30", "5:10:49", "5:12:39", "5:14:20")

> chron(times=time)
 [1] 01:48:55 01:53:11 01:58:18 10:04:01 10:12:45 10:14:16 10:20:24 10:21:59 10:23:11 10:23:40 10:30:40
[12] 10:34:13 10:39:47 10:54:33 10:58:43 03:21:59 03:27:38 03:37:58 03:49:00 04:20:42 04:30:52 04:37:39
[23] 04:40:08 04:40:55 04:42:25 05:03:25 05:10:30 05:10:49 05:12:39 05:14:20
> sort(chron(times=time))
 [1] 01:48:55 01:53:11 01:58:18 03:21:59 03:27:38 03:37:58 03:49:00 04:20:42 04:30:52 04:37:39 04:40:08
[12] 04:40:55 04:42:25 05:03:25 05:10:30 05:10:49 05:12:39 05:14:20 10:04:01 10:12:45 10:14:16 10:20:24
[23] 10:21:59 10:23:11 10:23:40 10:30:40 10:34:13 10:39:47 10:54:33 10:58:43
```

Comment: Short addition: Note that factors are unordered by definition! However, as R has everything you need, there is the datatype `ordered`, that is just a factor with defined order. If you replace `factor` with `ordered` in DWins answer, your datatypes will be more meaningful (though, if you only display the factor, there will be no noticeable difference. In some statistical methods it will, however).

Comment: My experience with ordered factors is that they sow confusion everywhere they go, so I do not recommend them to newbies.